# “I'm at a party?” (when you are a guest in someone's home)

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Suppose that you are at your aunt's or uncle's house for dinner with your family. Not really for fun. It's just a common gathering talking together with relatives. In fact you are a guest. Suddenly your girlfriend or boyfriend calls you. You answer the phone and say this sentence to him/her:

> Hi, Sarah/Alex. May I call you back later? I'm at a party and can't talk to you very well.

My question is whether I can use the word *party* in this context, or is it (*party*) mostly used when you have a lot of fun?

Comment: *family* party, perhaps?

Comment: A _family gathering_ or _family meal_ or simply _with my family_ are all phrases I'd happily use.

Comment: You can call it whatever you want.  Nothing wrong with "party" -- it's just a group of people together for some purpose.  I don't think the folks in the Donner Party were having much fun.

Comment: One thing a native speaker would rarely ask a boyfriend or girlfriend is ***May** I call you back later?* We would use ***can** I*. Yes, this might contradict some foreign language textbook which knows nothing about colloquial English, but that's one strength of getting to ask a bunch of native speakers.

Comment: The simplest thing to say is *Hi, Sarah/Alex. Can I call you back later? I can't talk right now.*

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to say is

> Hi, Sarah/Alex. **Can** I call you back later? I can't talk right now.

If you feel compelled to mention a place you can say

> Hi, Sarah/Alex. Can I call you back later? I'm at my uncle's/aunt's (place) and I can't talk right now.

This answer represents idiomatic English. We usually  don't use *May I* when talking with friends. And we wouldn't say *I can't talk to you very well*. If you wanted something similar, you could say *I can't talk freely now* but that is not necessary (and would rarely be stated) in this context.